# Formula for monthly sum by person

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, sum, pivot-table

I have an Excel page which consists of daily cash collections from different persons. My collection details are like below, in Excel:

```
Date        Name    Amount
1/4/2014    Name1   500
5/4/2014    Name2   1000
10/4/2014   Name1   700
5/5/2014    Name2   300
12/5/2014   Name1   800
2/6/2014    Name1   200
1/6/2014    Name2   400
```

I need to display monthly total income from each person like so:

```
Name    Apr-14  May-14  Jun-14
Name1   1200    800      200
Name2   1000    300      400
```

I used this formula to find total income from each person:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B8, A14, C2:C8)
```

but how to include the month-wise total?

Comment: If you add column then run a pivot table, that should be easy to do. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Yes @Jerry, But if i add Name in Row Labels and  Date in Column Labels I got the 50% expected answer. But this pivot shows datewise sum. I need month wise from this date wise details

Comment: That's where the addition of a column comes. You add a column with label 'Month' (or 'Period' whichever suits best for you) and run `=MONTH(A2)` (where A2 contains the date) in this column. The pivot becomes straightforward after that.

Comment: great good idea. I missed it. Thanks and i got the answer

Comment: Oh yea, or `=TEXT(A2,"mmm-yy")` if you want that specific format.

Comment: yes i finished like that only thanks

Answer (score 2):

PivotTables can be 'Grouped by':

[image: SO24329789 example]