# Excel Formula - SUMIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add values from column C (Number) based on criteria from columns A (Name) and B (Date).

```
Name(A)   Date(B)   Number(C)  Total by Name by Date (D)
Allen     5-6-14    12.75
Allen     5-6-14    2.88
Allen     5-12-14   1200.75
Doug      3-2-14    1111.11
Doug      3-2-14    2222.22
Doug      5-6-14    99.99
Greg      8-1-14    555.55
Steve     8-1-14    11.99
Zoe       8-1-14    77.33
Zoe       8-1-14    33.78
```

In column D I am looking to add up the number based on the name and date.  For example,

```
Allen    5-6-14    15.63
Allen    5-12-14   1200.75
Doug     3-2-14    3333.33
Doug     5-6-14    99.99
Greg     8-1-14    555.55
Steve    8-1-14    11.99
Zoe      8-1-14    111.11
```

I started off with this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "Allen", C:C)
```

which will give me the value of 1216.38 (all of the dates added up for Allen).  Now what I need to do is add another criteria to check if the dates (column B). I know this can be done using a pivot table, found here ([Formula for monthly sum by person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329789/excel-formula-for-monthly-sum-of-each-person)) but I am curious on if there is another way to do this.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is a sumifs function which will do what you want.  Watch the function input order is different as it had to be designed to take multiple criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `SUMIFS` function, that allows you to use multiple criteria, e.g.

`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Allen",B:B,DATE(2014,5,6))`

or you can use cell refs as criteria and copy formula down, e.g.

`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,J2,B:B,K2)`

where J2 is a specific name and K2 a specific date

Note that with SUMIFS the range to sum is shown first

Comment: Is there a way to add a date range rather than just a specific date? For example, one week's worth of numbers for an individual.

Comment: You can use a >= and < on the dates, e.g. if you want a 7 day period starting with a date in K2 you can use this version: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,J2,B:B,">="&K2,B:B,"<"&K2+7)`

Answer (score 2):

Wow just figured it out. Sorry to waste anyone's time.

Using SUMIFS...

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A, "Allen", B:B, "5/6/2014")
```